# How to save Multiple pages as a single PDF?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, images, cs6, adobe-bridge

In my CS6 version of Photoshop there doesn't appear to be a way to save multiple pages to a single PDF.  How can I do this in Photoshop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe Photoshop let you do this (at least not in CS6). The trick is to use **Adobe Bridge** (kind of a *file explorer* Adobe bundles with Photoshop).

It is actually quite easy with Bridge:

1. Open Adobe Bridge
2. Select/highlight all the photos/files you want to export
3. Find the Output window in top right of Adobe Bridge (if you are using CC [2017 or earlier], you will need to [manually install](https://helpx.adobe.com/bridge/kb/install-output-module-bridge-cc.html) the OUTPUT module as it doesn't come with Adobe Bridge out of the box)

[image]

4. In Output menu, change button to PDF (right side of screen)

[image]

5. Edit the settings to whatever you want.
6. Check **View PDF after Save** (optional)
7. Click **Save**

Enjoy!

Comment: Just for clarity, your question seems to state CS6 as the latest version, are you aware Creative Cloud 17 is the latest version?  If this is the answer to your question please mark it as the accepted answer, too.

Answer (score 1):

Go to File → Automate → Pdf Presentation

(a window will appear where you can add, open file or browse)

Make sure that multiple page document is checked

Other options leave as it is (default uncheck all)

click ok to save

a pop click on high quality print

click save pdf

**Other option without Photoshop you can merge or combine**

Download the small software [here](https://pdfbinder.jaleco.com/) Free

Install

After Install open the pdfbinder

Click on Add file button
Add your pdf files
A best option u can up and down the files as your requirement 
And just hit Bind and save

Answer (score 0):

In CS5 version have to use File-->Scripts-->Export Layers to files. There you set your output as PDF and its quality. After execution of the script you have to merge your PDF pages into one document with help of external software (ex. jPDF Tweak )

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure if this has changed, but you can actually achieve what the OP is asking for, by combining the two methods already mentioned, you shouldn't have to do this, but hey...
So first, Use the **Export Layers to Files** option, you will lend up with multiple PDF files.
Then, Use the **PDF Presentation** option, and browse to and choose all the files created previously. Select the **Multiple Page Document** option, and viola, you have one PDF with all layers as separate pages!
Hope that helps someone!